# Optimize FS writeFile to avoid heap out of memory on large file sizes

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

Mainly I need to open the `json` file, push data to it and save it again. 
That with a large chunk of data done repeatedly.

The thing is that I'm not being able to finish the whole read.

I have tested the following code:

```
var array = require('./test.json')

for (let i = 0;i<999999999999;i++){
array.push(i)

}

fs.writeFile('./test.json', array, function (err) {
    if (err) {
        return console.log(err);
    }

    console.log('saved');
});
```

And it returns:

```
<--- Last few GCs --->

[3632:000001B9DE56BD10]     2076 ms: Mark-sweep 577.7 (585.1) -> 577.7 (585.1) MB, 92.5 / 0.0 ms  allocation failure GC in old space requested
[3632:000001B9DE56BD10]     2174 ms: Mark-sweep 577.7 (585.1) -> 577.7 (582.1) MB, 97.6 / 0.0 ms  last resort GC in old space requested
[3632:000001B9DE56BD10]     2273 ms: Mark-sweep 577.7 (582.1) -> 577.7 (582.1) MB, 99.3 / 0.0 ms  last resort GC in old space requested


<--- JS stacktrace --->

==== JS stack trace =========================================

Security context: 00000364863257C1 <JSObject>
    1: /* anonymous */ [C:\test\test.js:~1] [pc=000002501A885DE4](this=00000101E000A879 <Object map = 000001EDFF6023B9>,exports=00000101E000A879 <Object map = 000001EDFF6023B9>,require=00000101E000A831 <JSFunction require (sfi = 000000F3AFACAB59)>,module=00000101E000A7A9 <Module map = ...

FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
 1: node_module_register
 2: v8::internal::FatalProcessOutOfMemory
 3: v8::internal::FatalProcessOutOfMemory
 4: v8::internal::Factory::NewUninitializedFixedArray
 5: v8::internal::WasmDebugInfo::SetupForTesting
 6: v8::internal::interpreter::BytecodeArrayRandomIterator::UpdateOffsetFromIndex
 7: 000002501A7043C1
```

My question is:

How to optimize the code to avoid these memory issues?

Appreciate the help!

Comment: Streams, used asynchronously, are much better suited for a large amount of data.

Comment: Can you show us a real, actual problem with real code so we can offer real, actual solutions with real code?  The only answer to your made-up, artificial problem is to stop making massive data sets in memory and then writing them all out at once.  Create small sets of data and write them out as you go, not keeping them all in memory.  Also, passing an array to `fs.writeFile()` probably doesn't do anything useful anyway as you write strings or binary data and passing an array doesn't know what to do with it.